# Solution of a quartic equation.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Suppose that the equation $x^4-2x^3+4x^2+6x-21=0$ is known to have two roots that are equal in magnitude but opposite in sign. Solve the equation.

This is what I have been thinking. Suppose $\zeta_1$ $\zeta_2$ are roots. Such that $|\zeta_1|=|\zeta_2|$. Then $(x-\zeta_1)(x-\zeta_2)$ divides the polynomial. I don't know where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: So, the roots are $a,-a,b,2-b$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee; What are you talking about? Where in the world did you get (2-b) as a root? Was that in something that was later edited out?

Comment: @ Brian_Drozd What does the sum of the roots of a polynomial equal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So at the most basic level there is a factor $(x+a)(x-a)=x^2-a^2$ and the factorisation is $$(x^2-a^2)(x^2+bx+c)=x^4-2x^3+4x^2+6x-21$$

Equating powers of $x^3$ gives immediately a value for $b$. Then equating powers of $x$ gives $a^2b=-6$ so $a^2$ is known and the constant term gives $a^2c=21$ so that $c$ can be determined.

Answer (score 7):

If $\pm a$ are roots of $x^4-2x^3+4x^2+6x-21=0$ then

$a^4-2a^3+4a^2+6a-21=0$

$a^4+2a^3+4a^2-6a-21=0$

Adding these two equations gives you a biquadratic equation for $a$, which you can solve. (Make sure you select the roots of the original equation.)

Once you have found $a$, the other roots are $b$ and $2-b$ and must satisfy $-a^2b(2-b)=-21$.

Comment: is there some obvious way to get b and 2-b out of that? I assume calculations would yield that but you state it in a matter of fact way as if it should be obvious...

Comment: @Chris, $-a^2b(2-b)=-21$ is a quadratic equation for $b$, once you know $a$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought there may be some formula or quick shortcut to getting that without just doing the algebra. Especially because somebody commented on the question itself just stating the roots again leading me to believe there was no working needed to get there. :)

Comment: @Chris, the cubic coefficient in $(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)(x-u)$ is $-(r+s+t+u)$. In this case we have that the cubic coefficient of $(x-a)(x+a)(x-b)(x-c)$, i.e. $-(b+c)$, is supposed to be $2$.

Comment: (Sorry, that should obviously be $-2$. Missed the edit deadline.)

Comment: @KlausDraeger: Ah yes, of course! Its so long since I've done this kind of thing that I've forgotten all those little tricks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)= x^4−2x^3+4x^2+6x−21=0$ Let $a,-a $ are the two roots given. So, $P(a)=P(-a)=0$
\begin{align}
a^4−2a^3+4a^2+6a−21 &= &a^4+2a^3+4a^2-6a−21\\
\implies 4a^3-12a =0\\
\implies a(a^2-3)=0\\
a=0,a=\pm\sqrt3 
\end{align}
But $a=0$ is not a root of the polynomial. Hence $\pm \sqrt3$ are the two roots of $P(x)$ because at two points the functional values are zero and the functional values are same only at three points. Now by the long division or Synthetic Division we can factor $P(x)$. $P(x)=(x^2-3)(x^2-2x+7)$. Now we have to find the roots of the quadratic equation $(x^2-2x+7).$  The roots of $x^2-2x+7$ is $1\pm \sqrt6 i.$ So, the roots of the polynomial $P(x)$ are $\pm \sqrt3 ,1\pm i \sqrt6.$